# Check contents of input field when the keyboard/cursor exits

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a system generated input field that expects it's value to be numeric & over 1,000.

This the **HTML** for the field

```
<input type="text" name="fr_goal" id="fr_goal" value="" size="15" maxlength="15">
```

I've got this JS running on it that gets me almost all the way there, BUT I can't actually tell if the value is greater or equal than the 1000 minimum value I require.

```
               $('#fr_goal').on('keyup', function(evt) {
                    $("#fr_goal").removeClass('don-active');
                    var value = evt.target.value;
                    if (value.length === 0) {
                        evt.target.className = 'invalid-amount';
                        return;
                    } 
                   else if ($.isNumeric(value) && value >= 1000) {
                        evt.target.className = 'valid-amount';

                    } 
                    else {
                        evt.target.className = 'invalid-amount';
                        $(this).val('');
                        $(this).attr('placeholder', 'VIP goal must be greater than $1,000');
                    }
                });
```

Now the `else if` is my desired outcome, ideally I know it's numeric and over 1000.

But what's happening is that as soon as I enter a number it defaults to my else case since the number is less than 1000.

Does anyone know of a way to listen in on that input once it's not "active" or in use to see what's been put inside it?

Ideally, I don't have to rely on a form submission to get the contents of the field and then present an error message. I'd like to be able to do it all "real-time"

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: maybe `.blur()` ?

Comment: @CalvinNunes that sounds promising! I'll have a look at that, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Calvin for suggesting blur.

I kept everything from the original question almost exactly the same, just tweaked the else if to only look for numeric.

Once the input field is inactive this function runs, and solves my problem perfectly.

```
$('#fr_goal').blur(function(eval) { 
                var userInput = eval.target.value;
                console.log("the inputted amount was" + userInput);
                if (userInput >= 1000) {
                    eval.target.className = 'valid-amount';
                }
                else {
                    eval.target.className = 'invalid-amount';
                    $(this).val('');
                    $(this).attr('placeholder', 'VIP goal must be greater than $1,000');
                }
            });
```

Comment: thanks again @CalvinNunes - would give you the accepted answer if I could!